# Creating value to several input type text fields from text file

Tags: php

I have 100 input type text boxes and would like to display the value to each box from a txt file.
I couldn't figure it out in PHP and thought it might be easier in JavaScript. But I am not familiar with JavaScript. My text fields are being displayed as:

```
<input type="text" size="13" name="contacts[]" id="contact0">
<input type="text" size="13" name="contacts[]" id="contact1">
<input type="text" size="13" name="contacts[]" id="contact2">
<input type="text" size="13" name="contacts[]" id="contact3">
```

So I need to add value the text boxes from `contacts.txt` which has peoples names in line by line.
To show as:

```
<?php include 'includethis.php' ?>
<input type="text" size="13" name="contacts[]" id="contact0" value="David">
<input type="text" size="13" name="contacts[]" id="contact1" value="Erick">
<input type="text" size="13" name="contacts[]" id="contact2" value="John">
<input type="text" size="13" name="contacts[]" id="contact3" value="Frank">
```

Here is the `includethis.php` file that writes all the names to replace the name tag to the index.php

```
$filename = 'pics.txt';
$handle = fopen($filename, 'r');
$datain = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
$names_array = explode("\n", $datain);

$count = 0;
$counter = 0;
foreach($names_array as $show){
if($count < 4)
{
echo '<img src="images/'.$show.'">';
$count++;

}
else
{

$count = 0;   
echo '<br><input type="text" size="13" name="contacts[]" id="contact'.$counter++.'"><input type="text" size="13" name="contacts[]" id="contact'.$counter++.'"><input type="text" size="13" name="contacts[]" id="contact'.$counter++.'">';
echo '<br>'.'<img src="images/'.$show.'">';
$count++;
}
}
```

Comment: Where's `contacts.txt`? I mean, is it online at the server? In the user's computer? Already in the page? Where?

Comment: same directory as the `index.php`

Comment: What's its format? And how will the program know what line to map to each `input`?

Comment: i need to add another `$filename2='contacts.txt';` explode that and enter it as values to each input type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$filename = 'pics.txt';
$handle = fopen($filename, 'r');
$datain = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
$names_array = explode("\n", $datain);
//contacts.txt
$filename2 = "contacts.txt";
$contact_data = file_get_contents($filename2);
$contact_array = explode("\n",$contact_data);
$contact_max = count($contact_array) - 2;
$count = 0;
$counter = 0;
foreach($names_array as $show){
if($count < 4) {
echo '<img src="images/'.$show.'">';
}
else
{
echo '<br>';
for($y=0;$y<3;$y++) {
  if($counter < $contact_max) {
    $contact = (isset($contact_array[$counter]))?$contact_array[$counter]:"";
    echo '<input type="text" size="13" name="contacts[]" value="'.$contact.'" id="contact'.$counter.'" />';
    $counter++;
  }
}

echo '<br>'.'<img src="images/'.$show.'">';
$count=0;
}
$count++;
}
```

Comment: what did you edit? I see the code is the same, only $counter+4 was removed?

Comment: need to break after 3 inputboxes

Comment: actually something is still wrong, can you check my edit. the textfields work but are only displaying first line 3 times

Comment: So you want to display 3 different contacts?

Comment: yes i want to display 3 contacts then break line to display images then break to display 3 other contacts until there is no more data on text files

Comment: Is there a way to trim the last 2 input type text so they wont appear

Comment: @blackfilms updated. By the way, I answered your original question so there's no need for unaccepting my answer.

Comment: sorry just wanted to be sure you were still there. Well your update managed to remove one. How about instead of removing 2 to replace with `images/empty.png` to keep them in right position

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you want. Anyway it's too late here, I am going to bed now.